# Access my bitvise server from the internet

Tags: ssh, ftp, bitvise

I have successfully installed Bitvise SSH server on our Windows Server.
I can access it when I am on our network using an FTP client like WinSCP or Filezilla.
However, when I am using a machine outside the network, the client can not access my host (ftp.domain.org).I have looked  at https://www.bitvise.com/getting-started-open-to-internet and https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-guide-opening and I should be fine (ports opened). Is there anything else I should check?

Could it be related to the router instead of the freshly installed bitvise server? I want to make sure that I have explore all possibilitie before checking with the network admin.

Comment: Are you connecting to it via SSH (SFTP) or via FTPS? The two protocols have different port assignments.

Comment: I am using SSH with default port 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By opening posts on the computer, you have opened them for access from
the local network (LAN), not from the internet.
From outside the LAN, your public IP address is that of your router,
not of your computer.

You must tell the router to pass those ports to your computer.

This is called
[Port Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding):

[image]

See the article
[Everything You Need to Troubleshoot, Diagnose, and Fix Port Forwarding Issues](https://portforward.com/).

The above link is to the Port Forward site, which will also give exact
instructions on how to setup Port Forwarding for your router model.